# Cordova Facebook plugin - sending message

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova

For my Cordova app I'm using the Facebook plugin for Facebook integration. I'm using the version from here: https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/Facebook and it worked well for login and sending message using the Facebook Messenger until I updated to iOS 9.

After following the instruction from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9 I managed to make login working again, but sending messages through the Messenger app doesn't work.

The "LSApplicationQueriesSchemes" contains the "fb-messenger-api20140430" entry in info.plist, but when I try to send the message I see the following error in the console:

**-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fb-messenger-api20140430://dialog/share?version=20140430" - error: "(null)"**

The plugin uses the Facebook iOS SDK version v3.21. I tried to update to the latest version from series 3.x (3.24), but I encountered the same problem.

Here is the code used to send message:

```js
var fbLoginSuccess = function (userData) {
    console.dir(userData);
    if (userData.status == "connected") {
        var options = {
            method: "send",
            link: "http://example.com",
            name: "Hello"
        };
        var success = function () {
            console.log("Message sent");
        };
        var failure = function (error) {
            console.dir(error);
        };
        facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog(options, success, failure);
    }
};
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Hmm if it is just a warning then you can probably ignore it https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9#faq

Comment: Yes, I can ignore it, but it doesn't solve my problem that sending messages through Facebook Messenger doesn't work on iOS 9.